# How to set borders in Rubik's cube using opengl GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, view

I'm developing a Rubik's cube game like seen in the picture. But I'm facing problems to set the cube face color with black border.

```
  public void setupSides() {
int i, j, k;
// Paint back blue
i = 0;
for(j = 0; j < dim; j += 1) {
    for(k = 0; k < dim; k += 1) {
    cubes[i][j][k].setFaceColor(Cube.kBack, colors[faceColors[Cube.kBack][j][k]]);
    }
}

// Paint front green
i = dim - 1;
for(j = 0; j < dim; j += 1) {
    for(k = 0; k < dim; k += 1) {
    cubes[i][j][k].setFaceColor(Cube.kFront, colors[faceColors[Cube.kFront][j][k]]);
    }
}

// Paint right white.
k = dim - 1;
for(i = 0; i < dim; i += 1) {
    for(j = 0; j < dim;j += 1) {
    cubes[i][j][k].setFaceColor(Cube.kRight, colors[faceColors[Cube.kRight][i][j]]);
    }
}

// Paint bottom orange
j = 0;
for(i = 0; i < dim; i += 1) {
    for(j = 0; j < dim;j += 1) {
    cubes[i][j][k].setFaceColor(Cube.kBottom, colors[faceColors[Cube.kBottom][i][k]]);
    }
}

// Paint top red
j = dim - 1;
for(i = 0; i < dim; i += 1) {
    for(j = 0; j < dim;j += 1) {
    cubes[i][j][k].setFaceColor(Cube.kTop, colors[faceColors[Cube.kTop][i][k]]);
    }
}
// Paint left yellow
k = 0;
for(i = 0; i < dim; i += 1) {
    for(j = 0; j < dim;j += 1) {
    cubes[i][j][k].setFaceColor(Cube.kLeft, colors[faceColors[Cube.kLeft][i][j]]);
    }
}
}
```

This method is used to set the colors in all sides.

My Rubik Cube image is shown which is given below

[image: That image occured through my code]

That image create through my code but i want my rubik cube color with black border like which is given below

[image]

Comment: If you're new, I'd recommend you to try something like LibGDX instead of going right into Android's API.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a rounded corner like the true cube I would use a texture map with a black border and transparent area which you wish your base colour to be visible through.

There is also newer methods of drawing shapes using paths but I haven't looked at these so I cannot advise how you could do those.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is rendering the face black, then render the face with your selected color with less height and width.

Also, render it a bit outwards, for eviting z-fighting.